# Can't connect to mysql database via command

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, administration

maybe I'm just missing something very obvious but I can't somehow connect to my mysql database which is installed on my local computer. When I open mysql.exe it says I'm connected to MariaDB and an ID. But when I try to access a certain database I get: "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database ..."

When I check for status, it says I'm connected as a user that has the name of my computer @localhost.

Hope someone can help. :)

Comment: `first' How to connect with command line ? `second` the correct way to connect with database base by command line is get the path of mysql ->bin on xampp and copy path in properties on command line `start in` your path and open command line `connect with database` mysql -u `your username` -p `your password`  if don't have any password don't write thing

Comment: I'm using mysql.exe which is in C:\xampp\mysql\bin     this is what i get: https://image.ibb.co/mXWe2b/cantlogin.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I guess xampp somehow blocks using mysql.exe for login purposes or something. When i use the shell from the xampp control panel, everything works fine. But I'm not sure on this.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a "drop in replacement" for MySQL, hence the name confusion.  (This is not a problem, just a confusion.)  (And there are subtle differences between MySQL and MariaDB, but you are nowhere near to them.)

When you installed XAMPP, a user named "root" was established for MariaDB.  And perhaps it asked for a password??  If you have not yet `GRANTed` any other "users" to get to the database, then "root" is the "user" to use.

The commandline tool `mysql` should also be available.  But it, too, needs a valid user and password:

```
mysql -u root      -- if no password
mysql -u root -p   -- it will then prompt for the password
```

If you are connecting from a different machine, you need more arguments *and* will need to have `GRANTed` access from that machine via the `@...` part of the `GRANT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Example of connecting directly to **db** named **iluminati**:

```
tenasimi@SANTRALSUM-05 c:\xampp
# mysql -u root -p iluminati
Enter password: *
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 806
Server version: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for Win32 (x86)

Connection id:          806
Current database:       iluminati
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    cp866
Conn.  characterset:    cp866
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 1 day 2 hours 4 min 58 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 2476  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 78  Flush tables: 1  Open
ables: 71  Queries per second avg: 0.026
--------------

mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_iluminati |
+---------------------+
| dutypersons         |
| persons             |
| products            |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye
```